# How can i call search tableview delegate with SQLLite

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

i prepared tableview. As in the screen below, there is a sqllite db. . But search delegate function did not work.

```
var dictionaries = [[String:AnyObject]]() //
var filteredDogs = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
```

---

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredDogs =  self.dictionaries.filter{(dict:[String:AnyObject]) -> Bool in

        if dict.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
        {
            return true

        }
        else
        {
            return false

        } 
    }
    //Update results table


    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RowTableViewCell


    if tableView == self.tableView
    {
        let row = self.dictionaries[indexPath.row]
        cell.language1.text = row["foreign_language"] as? String
        cell.language2.text = row["native_language"] as? String


    }
    else
    {
        let row = self.filteredDogs[indexPath.row]
        cell.language1.text = row["foreign_language"] as? String
        cell.language2.text = row["native_language"] as? String


    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let row = self.dictionaries[indexPath.row]
    self.speechText((row["foreign_language"] as? String)!, language: (row["language"] as? String)!)

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if((indexPath) != nil){
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbKv.png)

Comment: which array are you using to populate your UITableView?

Comment: dictionaries -->  native_langauage .             cell.language1.text = row["native_language"] as? String

Comment: can you post all your UITableView related code?

Comment: please edit your answer with that code, in comments is unreadable

Comment: Ohh. Sorry. I am new at forum. :) I added to below. Can u check it? Thank u

Comment: OK, welcome to StackOverflow, I edited your question with your code posted as an answer, then please remove the answer with your code and I will review your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RowTableViewCell


    if tableView == self.tableView
    {
        let row = self.dictionaries[indexPath.row]
        cell.language1.text = row["foreign_language"] as? String
        cell.language2.text = row["native_language"] as? String


    }
    else
    {
        let row = self.filteredDogs[indexPath.row]
        cell.language1.text = row["foreign_language"] as? String
        cell.language2.text = row["native_language"] as? String


    }
    return cell
}
```

---

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let row = self.dictionaries[indexPath.row]
    self.speechText((row["foreign_language"] as? String)!, language: (row["language"] as? String)!)

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if((indexPath) != nil){
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)
    }
}
```